# Using BotFramework DirectLine without Azure Bot Service

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I am looking to create a Bot integrating the Bot Framework DirectLine API that they offer.

But, I wanted the service to be Cloud Service agnostic. So, the idea is to use the BotFramework capability to start the conversations and persist the conversation cache using the conversation id it generates but the business logic can be on any cloud service (AWS/Google/IBM Cluod) etc.

Is it possible to design the same using the DirectLine API's with out getting bound to using Azure Bot Service?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot Framework works with bots deployed on any cloud hosting service, as long as you have an internet-accessible endpoint and a valid HTTPS cert.

- [This](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/693) issue explains on how you can run your bot on IIS or any other bot hosting service.
- One example of an unofficial implementation of directline that does not require Azure is [offline-directline](https://github.com/ryanvolum/offline-directline). This example sets up a local web server that emulates the DirectLine API and tunnels the requests through to your bot.
- With respect to hosting your bot on IIS or any other cloud services, keep in mine that
  **'The Bot Framework requires that the x.509v3 certificate exposed by your endpoint be current and valid. Most of the checks for "current and valid" are standard checks for server certs: the CN must match the hostname, it must not be expired, it must not be listed in a CRL, it must have the correct set of EKUs, etc.
  Most importantly, your cert must chain to a root certificate authority trusted by Microsoft. The latest list of these CAs is available [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants.aspx).**'

Note: **offline-directline is an unofficial private package and bot framework container support is not officially supported.** Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d51a0b42-d456-4c1b-ac6f-e2a1e673ef9f/using-the-microsoft-bot-framework-with-a-localized-version-of-the-direct-line-api?forum=AzureCognitiveService) answer on using localized version of Direct Line API with botframework.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The offline-directline seems to be only a work around for development purposes. Can this be spinned out as a service and deployed in a container to be used in production scenarios?

Comment: At this point of time, there is only LUIS container support available but there doesn't seem to be any support for the bot framework service.